# cocos2dx 2.1.2 android crash on launch on device

Tags: crash, cocos2d-x

I am using cocos2d-x 2.1.2 , i have completed working on my ios builds and now started with android build. I created the android project using create-android-project.bat and successfully compiled it with cygwin. Then i imported the same into eclipse, but when i try to run the same onto a device it crashes on the launch itself.
So next i created a new hello world project and tried running the same on android device, the result was same as before.
But the hello world and test cpp projects present in samples folder run properly.

following is the log that i get in logcat(eclipse)

```
05-21 14:09:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(322): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

05-21 14:09:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(322): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: nativeSetExternalAssetPath

05-21 14:09:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxHelper.nativeSetExternalAssetPath(Native Method)

05-21 14:09:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxHelper.init(Cocos2dxHelper.java:64)

05-21 14:09:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.onCreate(Cocos2dxActivity.java:60)

05-21 14:09:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at com.sci.test.TestApp.onCreate(TestApp.java:33)

05-21 14:09:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

05-21 14:09:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)

05-21 14:09:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)

05-21 14:09:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)

05-21 14:09:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)

05-21 14:09:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

05-21 14:09:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:138)

05-21 14:09:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)

05-21 14:09:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

05-21 14:09:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

05-21 14:09:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)

05-21 14:09:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)

05-21 14:09:21.693: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

any ideas where i might be going wrong. All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Make sure the name of the library that the java code looks for is the same as what the build script names it. Also, make sure that you have refreshed the eclipse project so that the built library is copied into the APK. Otherwise you can succeed in the build but the game wont find it when it runs on a device / in emulator.

Comment: Did u happen to get any errors while creating a new project via .bat file or during compiling with cygwin. I had the same issue and the problem was that .bat file was creating some files which weren't accessible

Comment: @baskus- i checked the names- both of them are same. and i have also refreshed my eclipse before running my proj on device/emulator. But the result is still the same.

Comment: @GaneshSomani- no i did not get any errors while creating the new project. The creation of project and its compilation on cygwin was very smooth and successful without any errors.

Comment: i tried to dig deeper into the log generated by cygwin, and i found the there is some issue in the method **private static native void nativeSetExternalAssetPath(final String pExternalAssetPath);** as it gives me unsatisfied link error for this method. this method is called through a series of calls in my projName.java file in the method   **protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);}**

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem.
I resolved by including the project cocos2dx/cocos2dx/platform/android/java, linking it to my game project and deleting the previous package org.cocos2dx.lib.